# Require Help using ROSARIA

Tags: rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I am totally new to ROS, I know really little about it. I have a task of using ROSARIA to run my pioneer robot.

Initially I also had the problem of Installing the package, but I tried doing

$ sudo rosinstall /opt/ros//electric/ 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=amor-ros-pkg.rosinstall'

I saw it got installed.

when I run rosmake ROSARIA I get the following error:

[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ROSARIA']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/mycomp/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111115-194506 [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ROSARIA'] to: []
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['ROSARIA'] [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

then I noticed that in my folder I had a file ".hgignore" missing in the installed in directory(when compared to the files here: "https://amor-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/hg/"), I tried to create but as it has no name I couldn't, I am not sure If i am doing the right thing and is that file needed ?? rest all the files were proper.

Need help in this regard.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11962/require-help-using-rosaria/) by [Puneeth](https://answers.ros.org/users/1389/puneeth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Puneeth,
Actually i installed the ROSARIA with some difficulty couple of months back in my desktop (with diamondback). Now i am using another system (with electric) where i managed to install ROSARIA today to check your errors.

Here is the procedure that i followed
First configure the workspace of ROS with the help of the following tutorials. Do not use the main installation stack path which is /opt/ros/electric..
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

Check with the following command to see if the new workspace appears with the following command.

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

And after configuring go into your new workspace and checkout the amor-ros-pkg, wg-ros-pkg, ros-pkg manually to it.
(I see some issues with the rosinstall way of installation so i do it this way)
For amor-ros-pkg

```
hg clone https://amor-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/hg hg
```

For wg-ros-pkg (where you don't need all packages that are their in this repo)

a) For teleop_base

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/sandbox/teleop_base teleop_base
```

b) For control_toolbox

```
svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_controllers/branches/pr2_controllers-1.4/control_toolbox control_toolbox
```

c) For joystick_drivers (ros-pkg has this only)
You can use

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-joystick-drivers
```

Till here you have just checked out the source for rosaria, teleop_base and its dependencies  in side the new workspace and installed joystick_drivers.

Now

```
cd hg/ROSARIA
cmake .
make
```

you can also do

```
rosmake ROSARIA
```

similarly go into the control_toolbox and followed by teleop_base (as this requires control_toolbox already) and do the

```
cmake .
make
```

Now you can also do

```
rosmake teleop_base
```

After this you are done with the ROSARIA installation along with teleop_base to do operate it from the keyboard.

Even i am a starter in ROS. I believe the rosinstall method that was given in the tutorial was to make life simpler than doing these many checkouts and installing them. But its not working due to the path clashes. If anyone has any other better way of explaining, pls do so.

Hope this helps
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4